# I do not understand this solution

Tags: javascript

I start by pointing out that this code works. That is not the problem! I just don't understand how really. As I understand it the chunked.push method ads a new array all the time. But obviously, it does not. It gives the right answer: 
[[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]

I simply do not understand what is happening in this code. It spits out the right answer and put several items in each array if necessary but the code creates a new subarray each time, no? No, obviously not - but I don't understand why not? Please help!

```
function chunk(array, size) {
  let workArr = [...array];
  let chunked = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < workArr.length; i++) {
    let last = chunked[chunked.length - 1];
    if (!last || last.length === size) {
      chunked.push([workArr[i]])
    } else {
      last.push(workArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return chunked;
}
```

Here is examples of some input parameters and expected results:

```
// chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4]]
// chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
// chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3) --> [[ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
// chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4) --> [[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [5]]
// chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10) --> [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Any error log or test data

Comment: Please provide test array.

Comment: @SudhirOjha It won't give error. Last will be undefined

Comment: No, it is working. That is not the problem. I just don't understand how this code work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's break it

This copies an array there is used a spread operator

```
  let workArr = [...array];
```

Iterate over every item in `workArr` array

```
  for (let i = 0; i < workArr.length; i++) {

  }
```

I think this would give you `undefined` at first run, because there is nothing at index `-1` in `chunked` (because at first, `chunked.length` is `0`), but it will set `last` to last element of `chunked` array

```
let last = chunked[chunked.length - 1];
```

If `last` has falsey value (`0`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN`, `false`) or length of `last` equals to `size` (be aware, that `last` should be array or string), then push i-th element (indexing from 0) of `workArr` array into `chunked` array as an array, else push that element from `workArr` into `last`, but `last` then should be an array

```
if (!last || last.length === size) {
      chunked.push([workArr[i]])
    } else {
      last.push(workArr[i]);
    }
```

then simply return `chunked` array

```
return chunked;
```

Comment: About "cloning" the array, the copy, or the clone created this way (using _spread syntax_) is only a shallow copy of the original array. If that array contains references, the references are copied instead of the obejcts being cloned.

Comment: Dominik  - thank's for a great answer! But I just don't get it when it comes to how it adds element to the subarrays. How do the 2 and 4 get into the array?  [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]. Explain that and I upvote you big time :)

Comment: Can you provide input parameters ?

Comment: When `last.push(workArr[i]);` is executed, it also adds `workArr[i]` to the last array of the `chunked` array. Try replacing `last` with `chunked[chunked.length - 1]` and you should have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! Now I provided som input parameters and expected results